# How to run a jar file in AIX as a service which will auto restart if crashed?

Tags: java, service, aix

I have several jar files which I want to run as services on AIX. The service must auto restart if it crashes/ends. How can I achieve this?

I have a shell script which is like this

```
(
    until java -jar Test.jar; do
        echo "Test Service crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning... " >&2
        sleep 5
    done
)
```

This works but I want to know if there is a better way to do this? In case machine is rebooted for some reason, the script has to be run manually. I am not an expert on Linux or AIX.

Comment: In Unix these are “demons”.   You will need root access to autostart after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/au-aix-autostartup-shutdown-scripts/) about autostart/restart service/daemon in AIX

> inittab entries
>
> Let’s look at a entry for inittab that runs a script. Suppose, we want
>   to run a script that sends an email to system administrators stating
>   that the box is available when the system come up.
>
> The entry for inittab is shown below:
>
> `mailout:2:once:/usr/local/bin/mailout > / dev/null 2>&1 #mail users`
>
> The above entry can be summarized as follows:
>
> ```
> mailout: The unique identifier
> ```
>
> 2: Run this when the system reaches runlevel two (the default)
>       once: Run the script and do not wait for its termination; init will carry on processing inittab. Iif the process fails, init will not
>   attempt to rerun it.
>       /usr/local/bin/mailout: The full path and script name of the command to run; notice that the output is thrown away to /dev/dull. We
>   end with a ‘#’ comment on what the script does.
>
> For completeness, here is the script in question:

```
!/bin/sh                                                    
#mailout                                                    
/usr/sbin/sendmail ‑t <<mayday                              
From: hostname                                              
To: rs6admins                                               
Subject: hostname P‑Series is up                            
The AIX hostname is now up, please check services.          
.                                                           
mayday
```